# Prestashop site Link to database cannot be established

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

My website has Prestashop 1.7.1.2. After I replaced the whole "theme" folder via FTP by the original classic theme one which is I customised based on, my website now has this message, but not loading anything anymore on the browser.

So I uploaded back the "theme" folder I had when the website was working fine. But it still stays like this.

I can log on phpMyadmin with no problem. I don't know what's wrong.

How to solve this? I'm not familiar with PHP or Database.

Thank you!

[My website only shows this now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL1EP.png)

Comment: Delete the current theme an reupload your old one.

Comment: Normally you can not change a theme only on the filesystem, because there are entries in the database, refering templates and others. I think, inspecting your log will show missing files.

Comment: I already did that, re-upload the old one. Didn't work. But thank you still, I found out the problem. The pw in app/config/parameters.php file was a wrong one somehow. And I never changed pw of db, it was working before. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Check database connection configuration at `/app/config/parameters.yml`